# My ASP Cntrols ID not appearing in code behind page (C#) How to solve this error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My ASP Control ID is not showing in code behind page (C#) even I rebuild the solution again and again. And the very first line of ASP which starts with:

[Blue Underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYUld.jpg)

has a blue underline. I am providing pictures of this error. Please help me regarding this. Thank you

[TextBox Control ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzSvY.jpg)
[C# page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQFvf.jpg)

Comment: Post your source. Most folks aren't going to follow your links

Comment: Can you check your inherits part. It maybe "WebApplication.SuperAdmin_SuperRegister_SuperRegister"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
foreach (Control panelctrl in UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls)
{
    if (panelctrl is Panel)
    {
        Panel p = (Panel)panelctrl;
        foreach (Control txt in p.Controls)
        {
            if (txt is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)txt;
                // do something with textbox
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if you have your controls declared in SuperRegister.aspx.designer.cs (mostly auto generated) and ignore this line if you don't find such file.
2. You need to specify **.Text** property while passing as command argument

Replace the below line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName",txtFullName);
```

with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName",txtFullName.Text);
```

3. Add **ID** attribute in below line in .aspx page:

It should look like

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" ID="frmRegister" runat="server">
```